# Maximum call stack size exceeded while integrating in react-id-swiper

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am Using rect-id-swiper for carousel in my project. below is my code.

```
class Slide extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      load: false,
      next: "",
      error: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    const token = getTokenu();
    Axios.get(ApiUrlConstant.getApiFullUrl("slide"), {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Token " + token
      }
    })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data.results);
        this.setState({ data: res.data.results, loding: false });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ error: error, loading: false });
      });
  }

  renderCompetitionSlides = () => {
    if (this.state.data.length === 0)
      return (
        <div
          style={{
            width: "100%",
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            color: "#f3990f"
          }}
        >
          <span>No Poster to display!</span>
        </div>
      );
    return this.state.data.map(item => {
      return (
        <div key={item.id}>
          <Link className="card" to="">
            <div className="swiperimgweb">
              <img style={{ width: "100%" }} src={item.poster} />
            </div>
          </Link>
        </div>
      );
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { data, error, load, next } = this.state;
    SwiperCore.use([Autoplay, Navigation]);
    const swiperhero = {
      spaceBetween: 30,
      centeredSlides: true,
      autoplay: {
        delay: 5000,
        disableOnInteraction: false
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
      }
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <Swiper {...swiperhero}>{this.renderCompetitionSlides()}</Swiper>
        {this.state.load ? (
          <div
            id="slide-load"
            style={{
              marginTop: "100px",
              marginBottom: "30px",
              width: "100%",
              display: "flex",
              justifyContent: "center"
            }}
          >
            <ClipLoader size={30} color={"#f3990f"} />
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Slide;
```

And I am trying to render [these](https://codeshare.io/aJ0BBn) API's
I think I have done in right way. but still am getting error on console and The images are not coming as I need. [click](https://react-id-swiper.ashernguyen.site/) here to check the react-id-swiper.

```
scheduler.development.js:178 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

What is the mean of above error and How can we fix this?

Comment: This usually happens when too many re-renders are being chained together. Check your components for where you're updating the state or may be causing a re-render. Hard to tell from the code above alone. Also, (unrelated to this issue) I would recommend moving the `SwiperCore.use` and `const swiperhero` outside of the render method as better code practice.